# Can Python's isinstance be emulated or used in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Python you can do something like this:

```
if isinstance("hello", basestring):
   print "hello is a string"
else:
   print "Not a string"
```

My question is can this kind of code be recreated or emulated using Rust ? If it is possible, is this kind of checking necessary or useful in Rust ?

Comment: What is the thing you have in Rust that could possibly be some type but you don't know which one?

Comment: @SebastianRedl, you don't know which concrete type a generic parameter has, e.g. someone with experience of other languages might wish to write `fn foo<T>(x: T) { if T is String { ... } else { ... } }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed. When you write for example a function `def foo(x):`, the caller can choose to give a value of any type as the parameter `x`. That’s why Python has `isinstance()`, so that you can check when it’s important.

Rust is statically typed. Any variable in the code has a type that is known at compile-time. For functions parameters you have to write it explicitly: `fn foo(x: String) {`. For local variables you can write it: `let x: String = something();` or leave it to the compiler’s *type inference* to figure out: `let x = something();` based on other information (here based on the return type of `something()`). Sometimes there is not enough context for type inference and you have to write an explicit type annotation.

If everything has a known type, an `isinstance` function that returns true or false doesn’t make sense. So Rust doesn’t quite have one.

Note that some form of dynamic typing is possible with trait objects and the `Any` trait:

- http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html
- http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html

So you can write:

```
fn foo(object: &Any) {
    if object.is::<String>() {
         // ...
    }
}
```

`object`’s type is still static: it’s `&Any`. But it also *represents* a value of some other, arbitrary type. You can access that value with other `Any` methods such as `downcast_ref`.

Answer (score 4):

Rust has a limited for a downcasting that can be provided by [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/any/trait.Any.html): you can `Any` to query whether the concrete type is `X` or `Y`.

---

The usefulness of the construct is rather limited though; Rust is a statically typed language so in most situation you:

- either know the exact concrete type
- or use a `trait` that has sufficient methods for your needs

still, Chris Morgan developed an [`AnyMap`](https://github.com/chris-morgan/anymap) for example to store one value of each type, without knowing said types a-priori, which he then used to provide a typed interface to HTTP headers without restricting the set of headers to a known set.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most similar paradigm in Rust is using the `match` keyword on enum types.  For instance, in the `std::net::IpAddr` case, you can use matching to decide whether you are dealing with an `Ipv4Addr` or an `Ipv6Addr`.

```
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, Ipv6Addr};

fn main() {
    do_something(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    do_something(IpAddr::V6(Ipv6Addr::new(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)));
}

fn do_something(v: IpAddr) {
    match v {
        IpAddr::V4(_x) => {
            println!("I'm an IPv4 Address!");
        }
        IpAddr::V6(_x) => {
            println!("I'm an IPv6 Address!");
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to Rust Playground with working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=99a0d2c4a559ca81a67f82693ad71adc&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This has the advantage of having well-defined types everywhere, which is of course required as Rust is strongly typed.  However, it does have a potential impact on how you arrange your data structures; thus this sort of behavior has to be planned in advance.